# How to get wiki page's last update date using Azure DevOps API?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-devops-wiki

I'm trying to get the last updated date for a wiki page on Azure. The library don't provide this property.
I am able to pull these properties: {path, order, gitItempath, subPages, URL, remoteUrl, id, content }

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wiki/pages/get-page?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0

Answer (score 1):

> How to get wiki page's last update date using Azure DevOps API?

I am afraid there is no such out of box REST API at this moment, however you can track it by tools such as Fiddler or press <kbd>F12</kbd> in Chrome browser then select `Network`.

We could to get the latest commit ID for the Wiki, we could use the REST API:

```
https://dev.azure.com/<OrganizationName>/<ProjectName>/_apis/git/repositories/<WikiName>/Commits/?
```

Now, I could get the all the commits for the specify wiki, we just choose the first commit Id to invoke previous REST API:

[image]

The date of the commit of the wiki is the last updated date for a wiki page on Azure Devops.